# C# Error - Object reference is reqiured for the non-static field

Tags: c#, enums

I am very new to c# but I am stuck. I have explained my scenario below.

Now I have a list of enums like this,

```
public enum Colors
{
   Black,
   Blue,
   Red
}
```

I have 2 classes with switch statements(I have shown just 1 class since both the classes are similar). Now I am getting an error like this `An object reference is requesred for the non-static field, method, or property 'RandomColor.GetColors'`. Also I could have used the answer version in all my class that uses this switch statement but since I want to do like changing value in one file and it changes that value in all class for me.

```
public class RandomColorService
{
   public readonly string _url;

   public RandomColorService()
   {
      switch (RandomColor.GetColors)
      {
        case Colors.Black:
            _url = "Use url for black color";
            break;
        case Colors.Blue:
            _url = "Use url for blue color";
            break;
        case Colors.Red:
            _url = "Use url for red color";
            break;
      }
   }
}
```

Therefore to achieve that I tried to create this class but now If I put static in the below class everything works perfectly, but I am trying to make it more dynamic so that I can change the value of `GetColors` from different class to a different color. So that it uses the appropriate url in the above class.

```
public class RandomColor //put static here
{
   public Colors GetColors { get; set; } = Colors.Black; //put static here
}
```

Can you guys help me with this error?

Comment: You may need to reword this?  I'm not understanding your problem, and can't see where you are trying to change the property `type`.  `value` yes, but...I don't think that's what you're asking.

Comment: @zzxyz Please check the edited question. And yes, I'm trying to change the `value`.

Comment: You're having this problem because you're doing it wrong. DO NOT try to write your own date handling library. Use the built-in stuff: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973825.aspx

Comment: @Jasmine I am just giving an example using "Days". It can be anything. My question is how can I change the value of `DayTesting`.

Comment: It doesn't make sense that you would be asking a question about the basic initialization of a class and subsequent access of properties though. That seems too basic for a real question. If you're really asking how to set the value of a property, that's not a legit SO question.

Comment: @Jasmine I have above mentioned switch statement in more then one class. What I want to do is that upon changing the value at one place (i.e. in TestDays class) changes in all other classes that uses the value of DayTesting.

Comment: "I have above mentioned switch statement in more then one class" - HUGE design flaw! When you start to have to repeat code in more than one place, it suggests your design is incorrect. If the whole purpose of this question is to ENABLE that poor design choice... then, well, I'm gonna leave my downvote the way it is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166278/discussion-between-nick-king-and-jasmine).

Answer (score 1):

The most straight forward way to change the value of a property is with a set statement:

```
var myTestDays = new TestDays();
myTestDays.DayTesting = Days.Sunday;
```

Comment: Since I have a many switch statements in different services. Thats why I want to change it in my `TestDays` class, so that it applies to all switch statement.